# Decomposing reflections into rotations on the n-sphere

Tags: geometry

Given an $n$-sphere, I'd like to decompose a reflection about an arbitrary hyperplane into:

- Rotations by an arbitrary angle in a coordinate plane (Givens rotations); and
- Reflections about hyperplanes with normals along each axis,

such that the number of rotations is minimized (but reflections are free).

It is clear that the number of rotations must be at least $n$ just from parameter counting, and there is an obvious strategy that uses $2n$ rotations (use $n$ rotations to rotate the normal of the hyperplane to an axis, reflect, then use $n$ rotations to rotate back). However, for the unit circle one can reflect first and then rotate and so only one rotation suffices.

Is this the only case where we can do better than $2n$ rotations, or is there a general strategy that uses less?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> "Rotation by an angle about a coordinate axis" actually makes sense only in three-space. Can you instead use "rotations by an angle in a coordinate plane" (which makes sense in arbitrary dimension)?

Comment: Ah, of course you're right - yes, rotations by an angle in a coordinate plane is precisely what I meant. I've edited the question.

Comment: Just checking: By *a rotation in a coordinate plane* do you mean [a Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation)? That is, a rotation such that its matrix has $n-2$ ones along the diagonal. Or, can it be any plane?

Comment: Yes, I equivalently mean a Givens rotation.

Comment: As for the circle, I think you can reflect first (or last) and do general rotations all in sequence.

Comment: It is a result of Lie theory that every rotation can be expressed (up to a change of basis) as a direct sum of $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices and possibly a $1 \times 1$ identity matrix. That is, you can use $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ Givens rotations.

Comment: Is this applicable here, though, given that we want to construct a reflection (that flips orientation) rather than a rotation (which preserves it)? Can you demonstrate how this would work for, say, the 2-sphere using only a single rotation?

Comment: @William The question here is about what happens when you don't have that *up to a change of basis*. Sam is asking about the situation when you can only rotate fixed coordinate planes. In other words, they are stuck with the standard basis.